# Rendering custom field manually when edit article in front end

Tags: joomla-3.x

When editing an article in Joomla frontend all the custom fields are rendered with the following code:

```
<?php echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.edit.params', $this); ?>
```

Isn't it possible to render the custom fields individually and not all at once. Then it would be possible the control the layout a bit more. I know, that I can group the fields, but I would like the render them one by one.

Comment: Thank you for joining JSE and posting your first question.  Please take our [tour] while you wait for support.